# Why does LazyVerticalGrid does not display correctly with a bottomBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a  [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) inside Scaffold and a bottomBar. I don't know why the last items are not displayed correctly at the bottom. You can see the area in the picture bellow.
[image: LazzyVertialGrid image]

Here's the code:

```
  val navController = rememberNavController()
  Scaffold(
     topBar = { HomeAppBar(navController) },
     bottomBar = { BottomNavigation(navController = navController) }) {
                  FoodstuffNavHost(navController = navController)
                }
```

LazyVerticalGrid (Inflated by by the NavHost):

```
@Composable()
fun FoodstuffList() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.horizontal_padding)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.h_space_between_items)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.h_space_between_items)),
    ) {
        items(Sample.articles + Sample.articles) { article ->
            SingleFoodstuffUI.UI(foodstuff = article)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I would like to know how to make the bottom elements show clearly, some part is hidden

Answer (score 3):

You should set the padding value from the Scaffold to your content. Like:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
       BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
   }
) { innerPadding ->
      FoodstuffList(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
}
```

This should solve the overlapping from the BottomNavigationBar. The Scaffold sets the bottom padding to be the height of the BottomNavigationBar

Comment: That was the solution, it works!